# Adding data of one table into another with some manipulation

Tags: sql, database

I just wanted to copy data from one table to another with one manipulation. I can do this with procedure. But I wanted to know if it is can be done by query only.

```
my source table(city) columns:
city_id, city_code, city_name, account_code

my destination table(account_city):
account_city_id, account_id, city_id

account table:
account_id, account_code
```

Now I want to move city_id from city into account_city table. And account_id should be taken by account_code which is present in city table and need to insert it in account_city table.

Can this be done in mysql query only?

Comment: You appear to be showing a "many to many" relationship. Every row in "account_city" says "account x is present in city y". This is a fact provided by your application - you cannot generate it in code without knowing which accounts are present in which city. Alternatively, you can create a query with a cartesian join, which shows all possible combinations. WHich do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use an insert-select statement. In general the syntax is something similar to

```
Insert Into (col1, col2, ...., coln) (Select ......)
```

Comment: INSERT INTO `account_city` (`city_id`, `account_id`) SELECT c.city_id, (select account_id from account WHERE account_code=c.account_code) FROM city c;

tried this and it worked